# trying to pull a github repo into adobe phonegap build but not working

Tags: git, github, adobe, phonegap-build

I have created an app using html, css and angular and put my files in a www folder. with the index.html file directly inside this www folder along with the config.xml file. I zipped up the project and uploaded it to adobe phonegap build firstly as a private app and it works perfect on my phone and everything. Now i am trying to create a public app, so i need to upload the zip file to a public github rep and then pull the repo into the phonegap build. however i am getting an error saying index.html not found.
my repo is called todo and my zip file within that repo is called ToDo.zip so the link i entered was
https://github.com/username/todo.git (username replaced with my actual username)

is this correct? thanks

screenshot of error 
[image: build.phonegap.com]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working thankfully.
instead of uploaded a zip file to github I uploaded the www folder (for the phonegap project) within the zip file. then phonegap was able to detect the index.html file.